# Remove decimals in pie charts dc.js

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I'm using dc.js to display pie charts, and I try to remove the decimals from the numbers but I'm not able to.

[image: pie chart with decimals]

Code:

```
addPieChartWidget(innerContainer, dimFunction, reduceFunction , colors){
            var chart = dc.pieChart(innerContainer);
            var dim  = this.crossFilterModel.dimension(dimFunction);
            var groupingStrategy = dim.group().reduceSum(reduceFunction);
            chart
              .width(innerContainer.offsetWidth)
              .height(innerContainer.offsetHeight)
              //.slicesCap(4)
              .innerRadius(0)
              .dimension(dim)
              .group(groupingStrategy)
              .renderLabel(true)
              .legend(dc.legend().x(18).y(18).itemHeight(16).gap(1))
              //.legend(dc.legend())
                // workaround for #703: not enough data is accessible through .label() to display percentages
              .on('pretransition', function(chart) {
                    chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
                        return d.data.key + ' ' + dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100) + '%';
                    })
                });

              chart.on("filtered", dojo.hitch(this, this.fiterChangeHandler));

        }
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your JavaScript? @Juanjo

Comment: This is definately not place to thank. But your question saved my weeks work. I created fake dimension (pie chart using three different column in dataset). My last requirement was to display percentage and it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `d3.format('.0f');` this moves values 0 places after the decimal.

```
var xTickformat = d3.format('.0f');

chart.xAxis().tickFormat(xTickformat);
```

Comment: it doesn't work. In the documentation I read that works just for "CoordinateGrid Chart". If I try it, it fails because it isn't a function for pie chart

Comment: Ah crap thought that would work, have you tried formatting your data?  `data.forEach(function(d) { 
    d.value  = Math.trunc(d.value);
  });`

Comment: the problem isn't in the values, is in the render, because the values are integer.
This worked for me, before the constructor of the chart:
dc.utils.printSingleValue.fformat = d3.format('.0f');

Comment: @Juanjo Ah fantastic! Do you want me to update the answer?